# angular js ui-route not working after minify angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hello I have made app using angular, I have used ui-router for routing, I have minified the whole angular app using gulp-uglify.

After minifying app, my child route(nested route) of ui-router is not rendering view, main parent routes are working properly.

Can some one suggest me what to do here is my route sample:

```
.state('masterPage', {
  url: "",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'src/app/Client/common/fullPage.html'
}).state('masterPage.userProfile.dashboard', {
  url: "/dashboard",
  templateUrl: "src/app/Client/userProfile/dashboard/index.html",
  controller: "userDashboard",
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Please show the definition of the controller userDashboard.  This usually happens because of injected dependencies getting mangled in the min process.  Look at the warning under implicit annotation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: there is no errors in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you minify the the app, It breaks the dependency injection. After minifying $scope is no longer $scope, they are minified variable like e or a. Which doesn't makes any sense for angularJS. To resolve this you can use **ng-annotate** for gulp and grunt and comment functions that need automated dependency injection using **/* @ngInject */**

Go through this link for more details about it. [AngularJs Minification and Annotation](http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/minification-and-annotation/)